# Visual Studio adds git directory one directory too high

Tags: django, git, visual-studio

For a Django project, I want the git directory in the same directory as the manage.py file. When I create a new python web project in Visual Studio it creates the git directory one directory above where I would put the manage.py file. How do I put the git directory in the right place?

Let's say I create a new project in a folder called "project_dir". The .git directory is placed there. Visual studio creates a sub-folder with the project name (call it project_name) and only allows you to add files and folders within that sub-folder. I want the git data in project_name.

project_dir
├───.git
├───.gitignore
├───project_name.sln
├───project_name
│   ├───manage.py
│   └───project_name.pyproj

When I create a new project I do not have "create new directory for solution" checked. I seems like it's creating a directory for the solution file (.sln) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way is you can create the project using command line and run `git init` command in your project folder. This will initialize the git repo in your project folder.

At the same level with `manage.py`.

Comment: Are you saying to create a new Visual Studio project using command line?   From what I've seen, when I create a new git repo in command line, it doesn't integrate with Visual Studio like creating the git repo through Visual Studio does.

Comment: Yes, you have to create a new project using command line.

This works fine with visual studio code. I am uncertain about Visual Studio.